# object to csv conversion dataweave component mule

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

### My input for dataWeave:

**Collection(i.e; List of 'Order' objects)**

```
    1st Order Object
    ----SampleObject1    (SampleObject is also a List of Objects that is getting repeated)
          --- SampleValue1    (some 'String' attribute of 'Order' object)
          --- SampleValue2    
    ---SampleObject2
          --- SampleValue3    (some 'String' attribute of 'Order' object)
          --- SampleValue4     .
    ------SampleObject3
        --- SampleValue5     .
        --- SampleValue6
    ------SampleObject4
         --- SampleValue7
          --- SampleValue8
```

.

```
2nd Order Object
    ----SampleObject1    (SampleObject is also a List of Objects that is getting repeated)
          --- SampleValue1    (some 'String' attribute of 'Order' object)
          --- SampleValue2    
    ---SampleObject2
          --- SampleValue3    (some 'String' attribute of 'Order' object)
          --- SampleValue4     .
    ------SampleObject3
        --- SampleValue5     .
        --- SampleValue6
    ------SampleObject4
         --- SampleValue7
          --- SampleValue8
```

For each 'Order' object in the collection, I need a record in a CSV.

### OutputCSV:

```
SampleValue1      SampleValue3    SampleValue5 .....   (For 1st'Order' object)
SampleValue1      SampleValue3    SampleValue5 ....   (For 2st'Order' object)
SampleValue1      SampleValue3    SampleValue5 .....  (For 3rd'Order' object)
.
.
.
.
```

I need the following output. I have tried multiple combinations in my **DataWeave** component. But couldn't solve it. The problem I am facing is, **I need a record in CSV for each Object.** But what I am getting is a record for each 'SampleValue'. Please help me how to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So your CSV is a TAB delimited file am I right ?

Comment: @Naveen Raj. Yess naveen. The issue is with not delimiter. It is with mapping. I am getting a line in CSV for  each sample value. But what i need is line for each object 'Order'. That too having only 3 sample values out of many say around 24 sample values per each order object based on some condition check

Comment: Please do comment if you need any clarification in the requirement. I need this to be resolved

Comment: Let me know if you need any issues

Comment: @NaveenRaj

Thanks for the response. I understand that some kind of Java code is needed. Will try that and definitely get back to you incase of any queries. Thanks

Comment: the java code is just to create a list of objects in order to be inline with your scenario. In your case you need to use just the Data Weave code and modify it based on the input objects

Answer (score 0):

Please find the flow below with the dataweave code inside

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="testFlow1" >
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['test']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <component class="org.test.MyClass" metadata:id="f70e8945-4d11-40ba-beac-dc2f352cc2ff" doc:name="Java"/> 
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv separator=" "
---
payload map {
SampleValue1:$.OrderData1,
SampleValue2:$.OrderData2,
SampleValue3:$.OrderData3,
SampleValue4:$.OrderData4,
SampleValue5:$.OrderData5
}]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <async doc:name="Async">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Naveen\OutputDump" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="test.txt"/>
    </async>
    <set-payload value="#['&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;']#[payload]" metadata:id="1e133033-b51d-43a3-a6b5-6496862dd510" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The following is the output from the above flow

```
SampleValue1    SampleValue2    SampleValue3    SampleValue4    SampleValue5
orderData1  orderData2  orderData3  orderData4  orderData5
orderData1  orderData2  orderData3  orderData4  orderData5
orderData1  orderData2  orderData3  orderData4  orderData5
orderData1  orderData2  orderData3  orderData4  orderData5
orderData1  orderData2  orderData3  orderData4  orderData5
```

The above code generates the CSV file with the header if you don't require add this at the outuput `"header=false"` like below.

```
%output application/csv header=false,separator="    "
```

The java class is shown as below

```
package org.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class MyClass implements Callable{

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        MyPojo pojos = new MyPojo();
        pojos.setOrderData1("orderData1");
        pojos.setOrderData2("orderData2");
        pojos.setOrderData3("orderData3");
        pojos.setOrderData4("orderData4");
        pojos.setOrderData5("orderData5");

        List MyArray = new ArrayList();
        MyArray.add(pojos);
        MyArray.add(pojos);
        MyArray.add(pojos);
        MyArray.add(pojos);
        MyArray.add(pojos);
        return MyArray;
    }

  }
```

The pojo is shown as below

```
package org.test;

public class MyPojo {

    String OrderData1;
    String OrderData2;
    String OrderData3;
    String OrderData4;
    String OrderData5;

    public String getOrderData1() {
        return OrderData1;
    }
    public void setOrderData1(String orderData1) {
        OrderData1 = orderData1;
    }
    public String getOrderData2() {
        return OrderData2;
    }
    public void setOrderData2(String orderData2) {
        OrderData2 = orderData2;
    }
    public String getOrderData3() {
        return OrderData3;
    }
    public void setOrderData3(String orderData3) {
       OrderData3 = orderData3;
    }
    public String getOrderData4() {
        return OrderData4;
    }
    public void setOrderData4(String orderData4) {
        OrderData4 = orderData4;
    }
    public String getOrderData5() {
        return OrderData5;
    }
    public void setOrderData5(String orderData5) {
        OrderData5 = orderData5;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I didnot understand why you have added many 'pojos' to an ArrayList, As I am getting only one 'Order' object each time. The condition checking part I can manage(as I already mentioned of all the 'SampleValues' I need only to write 3'SampleValues to my CSV o/p'). But, how I can use the 'Order' object that is coming from the flow in my "onCall" method. I have seen you hardcoding the values. But please let me know how to use 'Order' object and its 'sampleValues' in the "onCall" method. Thanks!! in advance.

Comment: method class to create your input to the Data Weave. In your real scenario you need to use only the data weave....you have the first sentence as Collection(i.e; List of 'Order' objects) so I created a object and put that in a List to create the similar input